# If stabilizer contains Sylow $2$-subgroup $S$ and another nontrivial subgroup $X$ fixing two points, then $X$ normalizes $S$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups, group-actions

Let $G$ be a transitive, nonregular permutation group acting on $\Omega$. Suppose that $|\Omega|$ is odd, then $G_{\alpha}$ contains a full Sylow $2$-subgroup $S$ of $G$. Suppose that $G = G_{\alpha}\cdot O(G)$, where $O(G)$ denotes the largest normal subgroup of odd order (the so called $2'$-core of $G$). Now suppose $1 \ne X < G_{\alpha}$ is a proper nontrivial subgroup of $G_{\alpha}$ and assume $X \le G_{\alpha}\cap G_{\beta}$ where $1 \ne G_{\alpha}\cap G_{\beta} \ne G_{\alpha}$.

> Then is it true that $X$ normalizes $S$?

This is used in a proof, where it is said it could be assumed without loss that $X$ normalizes $S$ by coprime action. But I do not see what should act coprimely on another set, the only ones I see is that $S$ acts coprime on $O(G)$, but this does not help me in seeing the relation between $X$ and $S$?

Comment: It is not true in general that $X$ normalizes any Sylow $2$-subgroup of $G_\alpha$. I can think of an example of degree $27$ with $G_\alpha \cong S_4$ and $|X|=3$. (This is $\mathtt{TransitiveGroup}(27,214)$.)

Comment: @DerekHolt Okay, thank you. But with regard to the last paragraph, when writing "without loss we can assume that $X$ normalizes $S$", is this possible, i.e. maybe it might be possible that some conjugate of $X$ normalizes $S$?

Comment: No because as I said $X$ does not normalize any Sylow $2$-subgroup. Also note that $X$ is itself a Sylow $3$-subgroup of $S_4$.